# MapReduce on Mongo Database with Docker ended up with connection closed

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a Mongo Database on a docker container. I have only one collection. Some data about my objects :

```
Data Size   1.96 GB
Storage Size    481 MB
Avg Obj Size    1.13 MB
Objects     1740
Index Size  77.8 KB
```

When I execute a mapReduce function on this collection, I end up everytime with a connection closed, either on the mongo shell or on my python driver (PyMongo). I don't think it is linked to the driver because when I request a smaller collection (with 10 objects for exemple), or when I put a [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#cmd-mapreduce-limit) on my MapReduce job (i.e. up to 1000), it works fine.
So why it doesn't work on the full collection?

Some additional informations:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

Docker ressources:
CPUs: 4
Memory: 2.00GB
Swap: 1GB

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my `connection closed` error by incrementing arbitrarily my CPUs, Memory and Swap docker ressources (CPUs: 5 Memory: 8.00GB Swap: 1.5GB). Anybody knows why it works now ?